# mv multiple files same dir without specifying same path or each

Tags: mv

If we have a dir/file setup like the following

```
var
  |-->usr
  |    |-FileA
  |    |-FileB
  |    |-FileC
  |    |-FileD
```

How can I move FileA and FileD without specifying the path twice like in the following cmd?

```
mv /var/usr/FileA /var/usr/FileB /home
```

Answer (score 5):

Try doing this :

```
mv /var/usr/{FileA,FileB} /home
```

or :

```
( cd /var/usr/ && mv FileA FileB /home )
```

The later one use a subshell to return to the previous PATH.

Check [brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace)

Answer (score 2):

You could just do:

```
mv /va[r]/usr/File[AB] /home
```

And possibly even...

```
mv /va[r]/usr/File[AB] /home
```

Comment: What's the point of the brackets around `[r]`?

Comment: @noumenon - they expand the known `/var/` path first so the stderr is more easy to test. i did an answer on it somewhere here that made more sense before - especially where `*` is used - but its not especially useful without variables. basically, even if you insert variables somewhere in the path, a filename that exists will always evaluate to `/var/...` whereas any broken or inaccessible pathname will work out to `/va[r]/...`